# Other means of paying property taxes

Tags: property-taxes

Probably my question is related to one of my previous ones, but it is most likely not the same. If a foreigner who doesn't live in the US as main residence and therefore doesn't have tax residence there (i.e he's not liable to US income taxes) owns a house in NYC, can he receive property taxes bills (or demands of payment or any technicay fitting name) via mail and then pay them via banking, or home banking in case he cannot pay them in the US?

Comment: This question might be best answered by calling your local tax authority in NYC.

Answer (score 3):

Most local governments expect that property owners will be handling their tax bills electronically or they will be sending them to a mortgage company for processing. The local government has their tax bills calculated, posted, and then due on a regular schedule. They have a website that can be used to see the assessment and the bills, and process payments. There is no need to depend on the snail mail system to get the bill.

I am sure that New York City allows all these transactions to be done via their website.

For my jurisdiction, I can mail my payment (slow), or charge a credit card (expensive), or have the money pulled directly from my bank account (quick and free). I am not sure if they can pull funds from a foreign bank, so you might need to transfer the money into a US bank account before telling the local  government to withdraw the funds. This should not  be a big deal because there is about 8 weeks in my situation between the billing and the due date.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly get the tax bill mailed to a US address other than that of the property.  Not sure if NYC will mail it to another country.  If not, there are services in the US that will receive your paper mail and then email you a scanned copy.  You can then pay the bill using your US bank's bill payment system.

Answer (score 0):

The [NYC website](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/finance/taxes/property-bills-and-payments.page) enables owners outside the country to view and pay the property tax bill:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNAyK.jpg)